# Append a list inside of a Dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a script to track donations below. My add_name() function is working up until I try to add the donation amount to the end of the list for an existing name. If the name already exists it overwrites the list associated with the name. I have tried append and extend, but neither work.

```
people_db = {'Bob': [600.0],
             'Fred': [645.0, 231.0, 768.0],
             'Sam': [4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0],
             'Faith': [742.0, 842.0, 542.0],
             'John': [432.0, 754.0, 10000]}

def add_name():
    name_person = str.lower(input("Enter Full Name or 'list': "))
    if name_person == "list":
        for key in people_db.keys():
            print(key)
    else:
        people_db[name_person] = list()
        people_db[name_person].extend([int(input("Donation Amount: "))])
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a new empty list for `name_person` only if `name_person` does not yet exist as a key in `people_db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two conditions (one when the user exists and one when not) so an `if` seems in order. Get the donation once then check the db for the name to see which way it should be updated.

```
people_db = {'Bob': [600.0],
             'Fred': [645.0, 231.0, 768.0],
             'Sam': [4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0],
             'Faith': [742.0, 842.0, 542.0],
             'John': [432.0, 754.0, 10000]}

def add_name():
    name_person = str.lower(input("Enter Full Name or 'list': "))
    if name_person == "list":
        for key in people_db.keys():
            print(key)
    else:
        donation = int(input("Donation Amount: "))
        if name_person in people_db:
            people_db[name_person].append(donation)
        else:
            people_db[name_person] = [donation]
```

You could use `collections.defaultdict` to do the `if` for you, but since your db is using regular `dict` already, its not worth the change.

Answer (score 0):

```py
people_db = {'Bob': [600.0],
             'Fred': [645.0, 231.0, 768.0],
             'Sam': [4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0],
             'Faith': [742.0, 842.0, 542.0],
             'John': [432.0, 754.0, 10000]}

def add_name():
    name_person = str.lower(input("Enter Full Name or 'list': "))
    if name_person == "list":
        for key in people_db.keys():
            print(key)
    else:
        people_db[name_person] = list()
        people_db[name_person].append(int(input("Donation Amount: ")))
    for key, value in people_db.items():
        print(f'{key=} => {value=}')


def print_hi():
    add_name()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi()
```

Output:

```
Enter Full Name or 'list': shmr
Donation Amount: 123
key='Bob' => value=[600.0]
key='Fred' => value=[645.0, 231.0, 768.0]
key='Sam' => value=[4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0]
key='Faith' => value=[742.0, 842.0, 542.0]
key='John' => value=[432.0, 754.0, 10000]
key='shmr' => value=[123]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case of python's defaultdict from the collections library.

```
people_db = {'Bob': [600.0],
             'Fred': [645.0, 231.0, 768.0],
             'Sam': [4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0],
             'Faith': [742.0, 842.0, 542.0],
             'John': [432.0, 754.0, 10000]}
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for person, donation_list in people_db.items():
    dd[person] = donation_list

dd['John'].append(5)
dd['Jane'].append(10)

print(dd)
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Bob': [600.0],
             'Fred': [645.0, 231.0, 768.0],
             'Sam': [4200.0, 5002.0, 100.0, 4302.0],
             'Faith': [742.0, 842.0, 542.0],
             'John': [432.0, 754.0, 10000, 5],
             'Jane': [10]})
```